# Thunderbird does not open when I use "send link" in Firefox 12.0

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, email

Thunderbird 12.0 does not open when I use "send link" in Firefox 12.0. Thunderbird is working and running. The usual new mail window does not appear.

In Firefox: `Edit` → `Preferences` → `Applications` → `mailto` is set to "Use Thunderbird Mail".

I tried to set this to "Always ask", when I try to send something, I can select "Thunderbird", but nothing happens, when I press "OK".

(Also, in about:config "network.protocol-handler.external.mailto" is set to "true".)

By the way, I use Gnome instead of Unity. Can this be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Go to the application called "Preferred Applications" and make sure you have Thunderbird selected as your mail client.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression that will be addressed shortly.  You can track this issue [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/990931).